# Is it compulsory that the second derivative is continuous around a critical point?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

In my textbook definition of the second derivative test for local extremes it says that $f''$ needs to be continuous near a critical point $c$.

What I figured out is that it is enough for it to be continuous at the point $c$ itself and not around it. Let's say $f''(c) = a>0$ is continuous, that means $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f''(x)$ exists and is equal to $f''(c)$. I will choose a very small epsilon so that $f''(c)-\varepsilon>0$ and of course $f''(c)+\varepsilon>0$. Now since the limit exists we can find delta such that if $|x-c|<\delta$ then $|f''(x)-f''(c)|<\varepsilon$. This can be rewritten as

$$f''(c)-\varepsilon<f''(x)<f''(c)+\varepsilon$$

And since I chose $\varepsilon$ to be so small that both sides of the inequality are greater than zero, then $f''(x)$ is never less than zero in an interval $(c-\delta , c+\delta)$, so $f'(x)$ is never decreasing there and since $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)>0$, then at $c$, $f'(x)$ started increasing and never decreased in the interval $(c+\delta , c-\delta)$.

So who is right: the textbook that says it's necessary for $f''(x)$ to be continuous near (around) $c$ or my idea that it is enough for $f''(x)$ to be continuous at $c$ itself? And a similar logic applies when $f''(c) =a<0$.

Comment: It is stewarts early transcendentals

Comment: You are correct. The stronger hypothesis allows a (arguably) simpler proof.

Comment: Oh i see this is really confusing, i mean i usually trust the textbook because it was made by people who know way better than me but this time i just could not ignore this mistake.

Comment: It is not a mistake. It is just assuming more than what is needed to make things more transparent.

Comment: Okay thank you very much.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the text.  The text does not say that a function or its derivatives *must* be continuous on an interval containing $c$ in order for the test to apply.  Rather, it is saying that *if* the second derivative is continuous, *then* you can apply the test.  There might be other situations in which the test applies, but the book is making stronger assumptions in order to simplify the proof (as @DavidMitra suggested).

Comment: Okay that makes sense everything is clear now thank you all.

Comment: @FadelHossamManour The claim that the proof is simpler with the stronger hypothesis is questionable, since weaker hypothesis than continuous demand essentially the same proof. Moreover, the book in question doesn't include any proof.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "me or the textbook?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: user85667 what is wear or stronger hypothesis?

Comment: A "stronger" hypothesis is a hypothesis which assumes more.  For example "$f''$ is defined at $c$" is a weak hypothesis, "$f''$ is continuous at $c$" is a stronger hypothesis (as it asks that $f''$ be defined **and also** continuous), and "$f''$ is continuous on an interval containing $c$" is stronger still.  Typically, the more you assume, the easier it is to prove a result.